# How to set Languauge hint in Google Vision OCR API for android in java

Tags: java, android, ocr

Documentation says that the API will recognise the language itself but when I input an image with different language on it, it gives random letters as output, as if trying to recoginse the images exclusively in English.

```
  TextRecognizer textRecognizer = new TextRecognizer.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build();
    if (!textRecognizer.isOperational()) {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Text Recogniser Not Ready", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      return;
    }

    extractedText= imageProcesser.extractTextwithOCR(bitmap,textRecognizer);
```

with "extractTextwithOCR(bitmap,textRecognizer)" being defined in another 
class as

```
  String extractTextwithOCR(Bitmap bitmap, TextRecognizer textRecognizer) {
    Frame customframe = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(bitmap).build();
    SparseArray<TextBlock> obtainedTextBlocks = textRecognizer.detect(customframe);
    List<Text> textLines = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < obtainedTextBlocks.size(); i++) {
      TextBlock currentBlock = obtainedTextBlocks.valueAt(i);
      List<? extends Text> finalist = currentBlock.getComponents();

      for (int t = 0; t < finalist.size(); t++)
        textLines.add(finalist.get(t));
    }

   }
```

I've read the documentation but this API is really new to me. So it'd be of great help if someone can answer this. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use LanguageHint as your source. To use LanguageHint, you must use ImageContext.
Your source only recognizes English.